# iOS-Swift How to update progressView

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app where i am downloading data from web.
here i am using cancel button to cancel the download progress,this works fine if i am in the same view controller and if i navigate to new view controller and return back to download view controller progress view is not updating but the download is happening.

This is the code i am using to download data

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
                downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
                didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL){

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    let destinationURLForFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingString( Variables.name ))

    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationURLForFile.path!){
        print("File Already Exists")
    } else {
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURLForFile)
            print("File doesn't exists")
        }catch{
            print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
        }
    }
}

// 2
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
                downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
                didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                             totalBytesWritten writ: Int64,
                             totalBytesExpectedToWrite exp: Int64){
    //progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite), animated: true)

    print("downloaded \(100*writ/exp)")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.counter = Float(100*writ/exp)
        return
    })
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
                task: NSURLSessionTask,
                didCompleteWithError error: NSError?){
    downloadTask = nil

    //  progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error?.description)
    } else {
        print("The task finished transferring data successfully")
    }
}

func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController{
    return self
}
```

Comment: How are you navigating away from the ViewController which contains the progressView are you pushing/presenting a new ViewController?

Comment: Actually progressView is in the same ViewController, but when i navigate from this ViewController to second ViewController and then return back to the same View controller and hit download button progress view is not updating but download is happening..Thanks for your reply

Comment: The download progress will continue as it will happen on a background thread, whereas UI updates have to be called from the main thread, this is one possible cause, you can place your UI updates inside the dispatch_get_main_queue block to ensure this. Otherwise, it may be the case that the view controller is being deallocated as you have navigated away, you could solve this by using a container view, so the viewController with the progress view isn't deallocated.

Comment: I have to add the progressView part inside dispatch_get_main_queue block??pls provide me some sample i am new to iOS developmen

Comment: Yes this will make sure the progressView updates are happening on the main thread.

Comment: Can you provide me some example for dispatch queue i am new to iOS development